# C++ Undeclared Identifier in Template Template Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, partial-specialization, template-templates

I have a C++ class that is templatized like so:

```
template <typename Operator>
class MyClass;
```

Where **Operator** can also be templatized itself into:

```
template <typename Param1, typename Param2, typename Param3>
class MyOperator;
```

Now, when I try to write a templatized method for the class, **MyClass**, I get an error - this code:

```
template < template < typename Param1, typename Param2, typename Param3 > typename Operator >
void MyClass<Operator<Param1, Param2, Param3>>::FunctionName()
```

Produces the error: "undeclared identifier" for each of **Param1**, **Param2**, **Param3** and **Operator**. 
Why would this be, since the typenames/classes are specified right above?

I know the example code doesn't make that much sense, but my ultimate goal is to partially specialize it to look something like:

```
template < template < typename Param1, typename Param2, typename Param3 > typename Operator >
void MyClass<Operator<Param1, "CustomParam", Param3>>::FunctionName()
```

So that if the second Param is "CustomParam", the function would execute a specific implementation. Would this work, even though I specify all the parameters as template parameters (since the parameter I want to specialize is the second parameter, but the first is not specialized)? Thanks!

Comment: please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter names in template template parameter are just informative (as names for parameters in function pointer `void (*f)(int a, int b)` (`a` and `b` cannot be used)), you should do:

```
template <template <typename, typename, typename> typename Operator,
          typename Param1, typename Param2, typename Param3>
void MyClass<Operator<Param1, Param2, Param3>>::FunctionName() {/*...*/}
```

Notice that you cannot partial specialize method/function, you have to partial specialize the whole class.